# Concatenating column vectors using numpy arrays

Tags: python, vector, numpy, concatenation

I'd like to concatenate 'column' vectors using numpy arrays but because numpy sees all arrays as row vectors by default, `np.hstack` and `np.concatenate` along any axis don't help (and neither did `np.transpose` as expected).

```
a = np.array((0, 1))
b = np.array((2, 1))
c = np.array((-1, -1))

np.hstack((a, b, c))
# array([ 0,  1,  2,  1, -1, -1])  ## Noooooo
np.reshape(np.hstack((a, b, c)), (2, 3))
# array([[ 0,  1,  2], [ 1, -1, -1]]) ## Reshaping won't help
```

One possibility (but too cumbersome) is

```
np.hstack((a[:, np.newaxis], b[:, np.newaxis], c[:, np.newaxis]))
# array([[ 0,  2, -1], [ 1,  1, -1]]) ##
```

Are there better ways?

Answer (score 60, accepted):

I believe [numpy.column_stack](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.column_stack.html) should do what you want.
Example:

```
>>> a = np.array((0, 1))
>>> b = np.array((2, 1))
>>> c = np.array((-1, -1))
>>> numpy.column_stack((a,b,c))
array([[ 0,  2, -1],
       [ 1,  1, -1]])
```

It is essentially equal to

```
>>> numpy.vstack((a,b,c)).T
```

though. As it says in the documentation.

Comment: I didn't see that one!! I'm afraid the mathesaurus web site is quite outdated. I wish hstack would do the trick without resorting to column_stack but it's good enough.

Answer (score 3):

I tried the following. Hope this is good enough for what you are doing ?

```
>>> np.vstack((a,b,c))
array([[ 0,  1],
       [ 2,  1],
       [-1, -1]])
>>> np.vstack((a,b,c)).T
array([[ 0,  2, -1],
       [ 1,  1, -1]])
```

Comment: Yeah, that's good, thanks but I thought that there would be something that could be done along the hstack way (I mean in a more straightforward way. To lower the cognitive load, it would be better to see and concatenate these vectors as column vectors)

Comment: a, b and c are row vectors. so it is logical `hstack` creates a row vector. Having `a = np.array(([0], [1]))` (and the same with `b` and `c`) followed by a `hstack` would be what you are looking for.

Comment: We could do it like this, but we could also just consider that these are all column vectors and it is supposed to be ok as far as numpy is concerned. The problem with this approach is you're already changing the shape of the vectors. In fact, I stumbled upon this when I played with some simple linear algebra in Matlab and doing the same in Python as done [there](http://mathesaurus.sourceforge.net/matlab-numpy.html). However in Matlab everything is a 2D-matrix, so we would get the result with a plain [a' b' c']. Unfortunately, using a direct translation `np.hstack((a.T, b.T, c.T))` fails indeed

Comment: Regarding the comment "To lower the cognitive load, it would be better to see and concatenate these vectors as column vectors)", why not just:
 
`np.concatenate([v.reshape((-1,1)) for v in (a, b, c)], axis=1)`