# How to use numpy's hstack?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, concatenation

I have one large numpy.ndarray array that I want to extract the 4th and 5th columns out of and put those columns into a 2D array. The [i,0] element should be the value on the 4th column and [i,1] should be the element from the 5th column.

I trying to use the numpy.hstack function to do this.

```
a = numpy.asarray([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
for i in range(5):
    a = numpy.vstack([a, numpy.asarray([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])])

combined = np.hstack([a[:,3], a[:,4]])
```

However, this simply gives me an nx1 array. I have tried multiple approaches using concatenate that look like these examples:

```
combined = np.concatenate([a[:,3], a[:,4]])

combined = np.concatenate([a[:,3], a[:,4]], axis=1)

combined = np.concatenate([a[:,3].T, a[:,4].T])
```

I feel like hstack is the function I want, but I can't seem to figure out how to make it give me an nx2 array. Can anyone point me in the right direction? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: A "feature" or whatever with numpy arrays is that transposing (`.T`) a 1-dimensional array returns the same thing.  If you really want to use `hstack`, you need to make them multidimensional first (or use `atleast_2d` or similar), or use `vstack` and transpose the result.

Comment: Also check this out for `np.column_stack`: http://stackoverflow.com/q/14741061/2379410

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this will do what you want:

```
a[:,[3,4]]
```

Comment: If the columns are consecutive, it may be a better idea to do `a[:, 3:5]`, which returns a view, not a copy, of the array.

Answer (score 4):

Just slice out your data as follows:

```
X = [[0 1 2 3 4]
     [0 1 2 3 4]
     [0 1 2 3 4]
     [0 1 2 3 4]]

slicedX = X[:,3:5]
```

results in:

```
[[3 4]
 [3 4]
 [3 4]
 [3 4]]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `zip`:

```
>>> c = numpy.array( zip( a[:, 3], a[:, 4]) )
>>> c
array([[4, 5],
       [4, 5],
       [4, 5],
       [4, 5],
       [4, 5],
       [4, 5]])
```